# Converting to a Double Threaded BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make this program work with a double threaded BST, instead of a normals Binary Search Tree

I have tried to look at other implementations both double and single to see how they are performed, but it still isn't clicking

```
BSTNode<Key, E>* BST<Key, E>::inserthelp(BSTNode<Key, E>* root, const Key& k, const E& it) {
    if (root == NULL)  // Empty tree: create node
        return new BSTNode<Key, E>(k, it, NULL, NULL);
    if (k < root->key())
        root->setLeft(inserthelp(root->left(), k, it));
    else root->setRight(inserthelp(root->right(), k, it));
    return root;       // Return tree with node inserted
```

Here is what I am working with. This function is meant to be used in another function called insert()

```
void insert(const Key& k, const E& e) {
        root = inserthelp(root, k, e);
        nodecount++;
    }
```

I don't understand how to make inserthelp work with a double threaded BST. The inserthelp and insert function a part of a BST class and the following code is part of BSTNode class

```
class BSTNode : public BinNode<E> {
private:
    Key k;                  // The node's key
    E it;                   // The node's value
    BSTNode* lc;            // Pointer to left child
    BSTNode* rc;            // Pointer to right child
    bool rightIsThreaded; //Returns true if points to in order successor
    bool leftIsThreaded; //Returns true if points to in order predecessor


public:
    // Two constructors -- with and without initial values
    BSTNode() {

        lc = rc = NULL;

    }

    BSTNode(Key K, E e, BSTNode* l = NULL, BSTNode* r = NULL)
    {
        k = K; it = e; lc = l; rc = r;
    }
    ~BSTNode() {}             // Destructor

    // Functions to set and return the value and key
    E& element() { return it; }
    void setElement(const E& e) { it = e; }
    Key& key() { return k; }
    void setKey(const Key& K) { k = K; }

    // Functions to set and return the children
    inline BSTNode* left() const { return lc; }
    void setLeft(BinNode<E>* b) { lc = (BSTNode*)b; }
    inline BSTNode* right() const { return rc; }
    void setRight(BinNode<E>* b) { rc = (BSTNode*)b; }

    // Return true if it is a leaf, false otherwise
    bool isLeaf() { return (lc == NULL) && (rc == NULL); }

    // Set/Get functions to receive value whether it is thread or node pointer
    void setLeftThreaded() {
        lc = leftIsThreaded;
    }
    void setRightThreaded() {
        rc = rightIsThreaded;
    }
    bool getLeftThreaded() {
        return lc;
    }
    bool getRightThreaded() {
        return rc;
    }
```

The bool functions are meant to return whether that child is threaded or not

Comment: You are using the word "thread" as something different from what people talking about threads usually do, right? If so, you'd better clarify it at the top of your question.